# Is there any way to upload multiple files at once in a table with a blob column?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a table called "logistica_files" where I store all files uploaded by users. In this table I have the columns FILENAME, MIMETYPE, CHARSET, BLOB, etc.

Today I know two ways to work with file uploads. Blob column specified in Item Source Attribute (which treats only one file) and Table APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES (which allows uploading more than one file, but then deletes the file).

What I would like to know is if I can upload multiple files using the Blob column specified in Item Source Attribute.

If not, if I can work with the temporary table, but somehow insert the files into my permanent table logistica_files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the file browse item type, and use storage type of APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES, you can nominate the 'Allow multiple files' attribute that allows multiple files to be selected & uploaded.

You would then need your page process to distribute those blobs as you require.

[image: File browse item type]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This method will store my files in a temporary table, right? Is there any way, using this method you presented, to save the files in my permanent table called logistica_files?

Comment: When the page is submitted, you will have the opportunity to transfer those records to where ever you need. Note the 'Purge file at' means these records will be retained until the session is over.